How do I use multiple small sqlite databases as secondary datasource for storing measurements by devices?
I have set up a database that stores measurement data for thousands of IoT devices. The table storing measurements (using foreign keys to link with devices) quickly became HUGE and performance dropped, data exports became slow and index maintenance increased. Now I am considering using a single small sqlite database for each device as measurement storage, since they are mainly used for linear charts and exports.
Is it possible to create, query and drop individual sqlite db's for each object present in the primary datasource, and can I use ActiveRecord for this?
For clarity: database.yml already is connected to PostgreSQL, to store device details.
I have read through the Rails and ActiveRecord documentation, but the nearest I found was having a datasource per model, and I guess I am looking for a datasource per object within a model.

While you could do this -- that basically means you are creating your own RDBMS. As an alternative, I suggest you explore partitioning the table in postgres. Each device would have its own table and resultant improved performance, though it would be seamless to the app. There are a number of gems that support this.

This idea falls apart as soon as you have to get data from more than device as you would need to connect and read from N number of different SQLite databases. I would instead consider how long you need to store the data and make sure to vacuum out the old data periodically.
